# Is "The weirdests" correct?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I am French and have a question regarding a plural form of some words.

I work on an English language website and want to list "the weirdests" issues I have discovered.

> This link title would be "The Weirdests". Is it right ?

I want to do the same thing with "the most normal" (in plural) issues I will find.

> The link title would be "The most normal" ? Or "the most normals" ?

Or is it a one-word form (synonym) to say "The most normal(s)" ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Typo, obviously.

Comment: You are making a noun out of the (superlative) adjective _weirdest_. While this is quite possibly acceptable (cf the best, the greatest), these nominal adjectives are usually not pluralisable. They are rather used as mass nouns. Thus, a list titled 'the weirdest' or 'the most normal' may have one or more members.

Comment: Unlike in French, English adjectives do not agree in number and gender with their nouns. *Les maisons rouges* is simply *the red houses*. So we would not say *the weirdests issues*. It would be *the weirdest issues*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a *definite article* before an adjective, you can consider a *noun* is omitted after the adjective in a sentence. For example:

> The young (people) should respect the old (people).

Therefore, you cannot use a *plural form* of an adjective in your link title.

*The weirdest* (issues) and *The most normal* (issues) or *the Weirdest* or *the Most Normal* should be used.